# Creating a sandbox to build a package that has a dependency for libxcb

Tags: nixos

I am trying to build https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan. I wrote a small `default.nix` file:

```
{ stdenv, libxcb, pkgconfig, cmake, vulkan-loader, assimp }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "VulkanExamples";
  buildDepends = [ cmake libxcb.dev pkgconfig vulkan-loader assimp ];
}
```

which I call with

```
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./default.nix {}'
```

But when I call `cmake .` I get

```
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find xcb (missing:  XCB_INCLUDE_DIR XCB_LIBRARY
```

What do I need to specify so that the cmake script can find the correct header files?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working, it seems I had to use buildInputs

```
{ stdenv, libxcb, pkgconfig, cmake, vulkan-loader, assimp }:

with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  vulkanEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "vulkan";
    buildInputs = [ stdenv cmake libxcb pkgconfig vulkan-loader assimp ];
  };
}
```